# What do the various stats mean?

Tags: mario-tennis-open

When making a character via the clubhouse you are given a variety of stats, however neither the game or manual contains any information on what each of these stats means. I certainly can take a few guesses what they stand for, but I'd rather have some concrete information.

The stats are as follows:

- **Power**

  - Serve
  - Stroke
  - Volley
- **Spin**

  - Side
  - Top
  - Slice
- **Move**

  - Speed
  - Acceleration
  - Agilty